# .bat file not running when executed by app as windows service

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, service, 4d-database

So, I have this client-server app which is written in 4th Dimension Language, that runs as a service so it restarts automatically if something happens to the server. This language has a built in function which allows you to run cmd commands and I have another java app in the same folder, that is in charge of sending emails, something my server side app cant handle. We use a command for running this jar from cmd and send the parameters from there, creating and xml for it to create an html from that and send it via email. The thing is when I run this command with the app running as a service, the command simply does not run, but, if I run the app normally, it works like charm, with no problems whatsoever.

At first I thought it could be the paths, so I got all the paths to be absolute, using the full route, yet it doesnt work still. Also I tried exporting the command as a bat and running it by hand, in the exact same path were the server is, and it works just fine. I thought that maybe the service needs some sort of admin privileges, so I started it as Admin from the service, but it changed nothing.

Is there any chance the service has some sort of limitation which doesnt allow the app to execute external commands? If so, is there anyway to bypass this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't make it work when it was running by service, so I made a bat with the command the service uses and pasted it in the Windows Startup Folder, so it "opens manually" when windows starts. It's not the real answer, but is workaround for needing to use the service.